# Hang up on HTTP Get/Request

Tags: html, c, sockets, get

I am not sure where/how my program is getting hung up. I am pretty confident it is in the sending or the receiving of the links... but even after searching on the internet for some help and also getting help from my professor, I am still lost, as to why this is not working.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LENGTH 500 

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{   
  // holds the value of the command-line argument
  char link[LENGTH]; 
  strcpy (link , argv[1]);  
  printf ("%s\n", link); 

  // break up link into the host and path -- use the "/"
  char _host[LENGTH];
  char _path[LENGTH]; 
  int slashCount = 0;
  int i; 

  for (i=0 ; i<strlen(link); i++)
  {
    printf ("%c , slashcount: %d\n", link[i], slashCount);
    if (link[i] == '/') slashCount ++; 
    if (slashCount > 2)
    {
       // i is at the end of the host   
       strncpy (_host , link , i);
       _host[i] = '\0';
       break; 
    }

  } // end for

 if (slashCount == 2)
 {
    // given only a host, copy the entire string into the host
   strncpy(_host, link, i); 
   _host[i] = '\0'; 
 }

 else  // get the path for slashCount of 3 
 {
   for (i ; strlen(link); i++ )
   {
       strcat (_path, &link[i]);
       // if slash at the end of host name 
       if (strlen(_path) == 1)
       {
           // set the file field to be index.html
           char t[11] = {'i','n','d','e','x','.','h','t','m','l','\0'}; 
           for (int c=0; c< 10 ; c++)
           strncpy(_path, t, 11);
       }
       break; 
   }
 } // end if/else 

 printf ("%s\n" , _host); /*success*/
 printf ("%s\n" , _path); /*success*/ 

 struct addrinfo hints;
 struct addrinfo * result, * rp;
 int sock_fd, s;

 hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
 memset(&hints,0,sizeof(struct addrinfo)); // setting the values to 0 

 s = getaddrinfo("::1","http", &hints,&result); /////////////// 
 if (0 != s)
 {
   perror("error populating address structure");
   exit(1);
 }
 printf ("entering tcp setup connections"); 

 // check the host name’s IP address — has a dynamic configuration(DNS)
 // but does not change very frequently 
 for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next) 
 {
   sock_fd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,
    rp->ai_protocol);
   if (sock_fd == -1)
      continue;

   if (connect(sock_fd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen) != -1)
     break; 

   close(sock_fd);
 }

 if (rp == NULL) 
 {
   // you didn’t find a good ip address to connect with 
   fprintf(stderr, "could not connect\n");
   exit(1);
 } // end for 

 freeaddrinfo(result);

 // sending the request
 sprintf (link, "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" "Host: %s\r\n\r\n", _path,    _host);  
 if (send (sock_fd, link, strlen(link), 0 )< 0)
   fprintf (stderr, "Error with send\n"); 
 else 
   fprintf (stderr, "Successfully send the fetch request\n");  

 // responding to the send 
 char buf[500];
 memset(&buf,0,sizeof(buf));
  /*  int recv_count = recv(sock_fd, buf, 500, 0);

 if(recv_count<0) 
 { 
   perror("Receive failed");    
   exit(1); 
 }

 printf("%s",buf); */                   
/*  while (0 > recv (sock_fd, buf, 500, 0))
 {
    printf ("%s", buf); 
 }
 shutdown(sock_fd,SHUT_RDWR); */ 
 exit (1); 
}
```

I understand that I have to send a get request, and I commented out the response part and saw that there was a successful entry into the tcp connection setup. I am just confused how the response should be setup. I understand how to use read/write, but I wanted to also try send/recv.

Any help is very appreciated.

The output that I am currently getting:

```
http://google.com/
h , slashcount: 0
t , slashcount: 0
t , slashcount: 0
p , slashcount: 0
: , slashcount: 0
/ , slashcount: 0
/ , slashcount: 1
g , slashcount: 2
o , slashcount: 2
o , slashcount: 2
g , slashcount: 2
l , slashcount: 2
e , slashcount: 2
. , slashcount: 2
c , slashcount: 2
o , slashcount: 2
m , slashcount: 2
/ , slashcount: 2
http://google.com
index.html
Successfully send the fetch request
entering tcp setup connections
```

Comment: You should print out each address as you try to connect to it, for debugging. Also, print whether the connect succeeded. Also, wait a few minutes for each attempt, because sometimes the timeout is really high.

Comment: the code should check that 'argc' is 2 before accessing 'argv[1]' and should print a 'usage' message then exit if 'argc' is not 2

Comment: in main, this line: if (slashCount > 2)' is making some invalid assumptions about the overall format the host address.  Be much better to be checking of the link termination byte '\0' as this is acceptable: 'http://www.google.com' as well as : 'http://www.google.com/?query='hello/son' and lots of other possibliites

Comment: this code bloc: '  for (int c=0; c< 10 ; c++)
           strncpy(_path, t, 11);' copies the same string into the same place 10 times.  Probably not what you actually want to do

Comment: at the bottom of the 'for' loop, that contains this: 'close(sock_fd);' there needs to be an additional statement: 'exit( EXIT_FAILURE );''

Comment: do not use leading '_' in the variable names, as that can conflict with what the compiler produces.

Comment: perhaps this would be instructive: <http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~jrb/tcpip/lectures/pdfs/sockets.pdf> or this: <http://www.linuxhowtos.org/C_C++/socket.htm>, which includes links to actual C code examples

Comment: You might like to compile your code with symbole (`-g` for gcc) and run using a debugger, tracing throught the code. I wonder why your prof didn't already advice you to do so.

Comment: This would be easier with `libcurl`.

Comment: This line is very, very suspect: `for (i ; strlen(link); i++ )`

Comment: @abligh I cannot use lib curl.

Comment: @user3629249 The links are not working. But thanks so much for the other tips! Not sure what you mean by "checking of the link termination byte '\0'" I have gone through and made the changes.

Comment: @Marian I was able to see the correct print out of the path variable with that line. Is there something else wrong that I am not catching. I thought it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return value of `recv()` indicates `Connection refused`, which suggests issues with the setup of the socket.

You need to reverse the order of the two lines:

```
hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
memset(&hints,0,sizeof(struct addrinfo)); // setting the values to 0
```

so that you assign the `ai_socktype` *after* setting the memory to zeros.

On the `getaddrinfo()` call pass as first argument the string `link` received from cli (`::1` is an alias for `localhost`).

```
s = getaddrinfo(link,"http", &hints,&result); ///////////////
```

Changing the code results in:

```
woof@fth ~ % ./test.o google.com        
google.com
sock_fd=3
socket opened
Successfully sent the fetch request
HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Date: Sun, 25 Jan 2015 11:07:09 GMT
Server: sffe
Content-Length: 1425
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.02

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
  <meta charset=utf-8>
  <meta name=viewport content="initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
  <title>Error 404 (Not Found)!!1</title>
  <style>
    *{margin:0;padding:0}html,code{font:15px/22px arial,sans-serif}%
```

which means the server responded.

The file was not found because in the line

```
sprintf (link, "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" "Host: %s\r\n\r\n", _path,    _host);
```

you request a non-existing path; if you try with

```
sprintf (link, "GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n");
```

you should see something different (probably another error). If you want to get a different path you need to insert it properly inside the request (work on identifying it from the input string).

---

The code I compiled is almost the same as yours:

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>


#define LENGTH 500 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // holds the value of the command-line argument
    char link[LENGTH]; 
    strcpy (link , argv[1]);  
    printf ("%s\n", link); 

    // break up link into the host and path -- use the "/"
    char _host[LENGTH];
    char _path[LENGTH]; 
    int slashCount = 0;
    int i,c; 

    for (i=0 ; i<strlen(link); i++) {

        if (link[i] == '/')
            slashCount ++; 

        if (slashCount > 2) {
            // i is at the end of the host   
            strncpy (_host , link , i);
            _host[i] = '\0';
            break; 
        }
    }

    if (slashCount == 2) {
        // given only a host, copy the entire string into the host
        strncpy(_host, link, i); 
        _host[i] = '\0'; 
    }
    else {
        // get the path for slashCount of 3 
        for (i ; strlen(link); i++ ) {
            strcat (_path, &link[i]);
            // if slash at the end of host name 
            if (strlen(_path) == 1)
            {
                // set the file field to be index.html
                char t[11] = {'i','n','d','e','x','.','h','t','m','l','\0'}; 
                strncpy(_path, t, 11);
            }
            break; 
        }
    } // end if/else 

    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *result, *rp;
    int sock_fd, s;

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(struct addrinfo)); // setting the values to 0 
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM; // tcp socket

    // create addrinfo structure with parameters to initialize a socket
    s = getaddrinfo("::1","8080", &hints,&result); /////////////// 

    if( s!=0 ) {
        perror("error populating address structure");
        exit(1);
    }

    char temp[5000];

    // check the host name’s IP address — has a dynamic configuration(DNS)
    // but does not change very frequently 
    for( rp=result; rp!=NULL; rp=rp->ai_next ) {
        sock_fd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype,rp->ai_protocol);
        fprintf(stderr,"sock_fd=%d\n",sock_fd);

        if (sock_fd == -1)
            continue;

        // exit loop on success
        if( connect(sock_fd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen)==0 )
            break;
        else
            close(sock_fd);
    }

    if( rp==NULL ) {
        // you didn’t find a good ip address to connect with 
        fprintf(stderr, "could not connect\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else
        printf("socket opened\n");

    freeaddrinfo(result);


    // formatting the request string
    sprintf (link, "GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\n" "Host: %s\r\n\r\n", _path,    _host);  
    // sending the request
    if( send(sock_fd, link, strlen(link), 0)<0 )
        fprintf(stderr, "Error with send\n");
    else 
        fprintf (stderr, "Successfully sent the fetch request\n");  

    // response buffer
    char buf[500];
    memset(&buf,0,sizeof(buf));

    int recv_count = recv(sock_fd, buf, 500, 0);

    if( recv_count<0 ){
       perror("Receive failed");    
       exit(1); 
    }

    printf("%s",buf);
/*  while (0 > recv (sock_fd, buf, 500, 0))
 {
    printf ("%s", buf); 
 }
 shutdown(sock_fd,SHUT_RDWR); */ 
    exit (0); 
}
```

Changed the function call and restored the `sprintf` formatting the GET request. You should launch on a separate terminal the command

```
echo "Here is a message" | nc -l -6 8080
```

which suspends execution until you receive a request on the port (flag `-l`, see the [netcat manual](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) for more on this).

The request is printed on the netcat terminal and the process terminates, while on the terminal where you launched the compiled code you should see the message echoed and piped inside netcat.

Comment: I do not get this output though. The program chokes at the perror: error populating address structure: Undefined error: 0

Comment: My professor said that there is a line we were supposed to run on our own local server, but whenever I try to run the line: echo "Here is a message" | nc -l -6 8080, I never get a response and have to ^C out just to get the next prompt. I think it should be done in the terminal shell, right?

Comment: The line is not meant to print on stdout. I'm not familiar with netcat but I guess it pipes an echo to any request made on the port specified. Try specifying the 8080 port in the `getaddress()`, using as first argument `::1` and letting nc run on a terminal. I'm away from PC atm so let me know if you get it to work, else I can try it in 12.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. Im taking a networking class, and I am quite confused about some of these things. I haven't been able to get any response from the servers that I attempt to GET to. I even copied the code you posted exactly into another file and still didn't get the same output.

Comment: Not even a server error? That would mean that a connection was established. Could you describe the output you see when executing the code above?

Comment: BITSs-Air:CS450 ashley$ ./a.out http://google.com
http://google.com
error populating address structure: Undefined error: 0

Comment: from the call to getaddrinfo.

Comment: I edited the answer, check it out. Can't find much related to the `Undefined error`, it may mean that the function could not resolve the host name given in the first parameter.

Comment: Thanks you sooooo much for helping me! I can't express how grateful I am. That is definitely working and the request sent.

Comment: Don't worry about rep, I'm glad you solved the issue. Networking can be a bit boring, but there is a lot of things to know and if you can get a general view of the whole protocol stack it will be easier to go deeper when required.

Good luck with the class

Comment: Thanks, and I will surely do well. :)